# Strings - Number guessing game

Tags: java, string

This is a game that generates a random 4 digit number and then lets the user input 5 chances to guess the game and returns a hint as to how many numbers were in the correct place and how many matched but were in the wrong place.

I am having a problem comparing two strings. One of the strings holds the correct answer to the game, the other string holds the most recent 4 digit guess.

`aCount` needs to be the number of characters that are in correct position.

`bCount` needs to be the number of characters that are in the correct answer, but not in correct position.

`bCount` is the part I'm having trouble with (it's not working as I expect). I thought I might try a double for loop, but I'm not sure.

```
    static String getHint(String guess, String answer){
    int aCount=0;   
    int bCount=0;
    String hintString="";
    for (int i =0; i<answer.length(); i++){
        char guessAChar = guess.charAt(i);
        char ansAChar = answer.charAt(i);
        if(guessAChar == ansAChar){
            aCount++;
        }
    }

    for (int indexOfGuess = 0; indexOfGuess < answer.length(); indexOfGuess++)
      {
         for (int indexOfActualNumber = 0; indexOfActualNumber < answer.length(); indexOfActualNumber++)
         {
           if (guess.charAt(indexOfGuess) == (answer.charAt(indexOfActualNumber)))
           {
              bCount++;
           }
         }
      }
    bCount = bCount - aCount;
    hintString =("Your hint is: \n"+aCount+"A" + bCount + "B");
    return hintString;
    }
}
```

EDIT: This problem has been solved: This method now searches and outputs how many numbers in each string match, and how many in each position are the same!

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Please, try to formulate an specific question.

Comment: Give us some sample input/output. What if someone guesses 1111 and then correct number is 1234. Is `b` supposed to be 4, or 1?

Comment: Welcome to SO! First post tip: Only explain the part of the problem that we _need_ to know and ask a _specific_ question with a `?`. Many people are going to see that paragraph and instantly move on, or search for a `?`, not find one in your post, and then move on.

Comment: I guess my real question is, what is the best way to figure out if two strings contain 1) the same elements but in any order For Example: secret number is 1234 you guess 2136, i need to tell user that you have 2 numbers that are in the final answer in your guess but are in the wrong postion.

Comment: I don't actually see any string comparisons, just `char`. Since `char` is a primitive the use of `==` is just fine.

Comment: @BigSceeze  Your latest comment looks like you were intending to go onto a 2) but forgot.  You also forgot to add a '?'!

Comment: Hint is suppost to be in the form nAkB where A is the number of correct numbers in the correct positon, and B is the number of numbers that are part of answer but in wrong postion: Example: answer =1234 guess = 5271

Comment: then the hint should be 1A1B

Comment: yes, I have been in the complier to much and keep hitting enter and it sends my comments! Thanks for the responses so quick, I am still working, I don't want to post the whole program but I still havent gotten the method to work yet.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So bCount is determining the number of digits that are in the answer, but not in the right place.  So let's try this:

```
public string bCount()
{
  for (int indexOfGuess = 0; indexOfGuess < answer.length(); indexOfGuess++)
  {
     for (int indexOfActualNumber = 0; indexOfActualNumber < answer.length(); indexOfActualNumber++)
     {
       if (guess.charAt(indexOfGuess).equals(answer.charAt(indexOfActualNumber))
       {
          bCount++;
       }
     }
  }
}
```

This method does:

1. Creates an outer loop that loops through each index of the "guess" array
2. Creates an inner loop that, while the "guess" array is at an index, the inner loop will loop through each index (so while "guess" is at index 0, "answer" will go through all indexes before "guess" goes to 1, and then the inner loop runs again)
3. Check to see if the number at the guess index = number at the actual index.
4. If it is, increment bCount.

The only issue which I haven't taken care of for you is if the number is entered twice.  Example: if the number is 1900, and you guess 1909, you number for bCount will be higher than it should be.  However, I'll leave that to you as this is a homework assignment after all.

Comment: Doesn't matter. The function checks the actual contents of the string, the == operator checks whether the references to the objects are equal.

Comment: Plus, it's good practice to use .equals() to prevent issue with actual Strings in the future.

Comment: char != String  There are no references since they are value types.

Comment: `char` is a primitive (not an object). It's not located on `stack` and not on `heap`.

Comment: I am going to try this, will let you know asap

Comment: True. I completely forgot i used ChatAt(). Whoops.

Comment: only thing I am not sure of is this indexOf, not heard of that, will have to work with it

Comment: It's just the name of the variable I used. You could easily use i and j and get the same result.

Comment: The reason I am using strings in this case is because my assignment calls for this

Comment: This is it! Thanks so much! I have to change the .equals to == becuase I was getting complie error

Comment: Good to hear. Even though I may have goofed slightly with the .charAt() and ==, I'm quite surprised about the downvotes. If anyone would like to comment why you downvoted, it would be appreciated so I can improve on future answers.

Comment: I have been trying to up Vote the answer up but my reputation is to low, this works perfect and is the exact solution i needed giving me exact output I needed! thanks again Mike!

Comment: @BigSceeze you can always come back and upvote later if you remember!

Comment: Edit removed. And I know what you mean by not enough rep. I had the same issue until just a few minutes ago haha.

Comment: Oh yes Mike, also I ended up doing something like bCount = bCount - aCount as to account for numbers already accounted for in the right positon! Thanks for helping with this, feels great to have someone help you with a problem you have been thinking about for hours!

Answer (score 0):

Variable `bCount` is the amount of numbers in the final string, but not in the right spot.  You need a double loop for this to check each character in each string to see if they match.  This might point you in the right direction.

```
int outer_counter = 0;
for(char g : guess.toCharArray())
{
     int inner_counter = 0;
     for(char a : answer.toCharArray())    
      {
           if(g == a && inner_counter != outer_counter)
           {
               bCount++;
           }
           inner_counter++;
      }
      outer_counter++;
 }
```

The counters make sure these are NOT in the same position.

Comment: That's not quite correct. You'll need to decrement by aCount because bCount should only include characters that are the same but not in the same relative position.

Comment: ah he edited the question while I was writing this up.  That wasn't a rule before

Comment: This doesn't look like Java. Although, all that you need to do is replace *foreach* with *for* and *in* with *:* :P

Comment: Haha wrote it in C#, didn't notice the tag, changed the code example to java.  Sorry!